# cx_Oracle cannot locate 64 bit oracle client library despite the installation

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, instantclient

I've been trying to use the python cx_Oracle module and it continuously throws the error -

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
```

As a prerequisite for it to work, i followed all the instructions mentioned in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
I'm trying this on Windows 10 machine.

Here are the steps I followed -

1. `pip install --<proxy details> cx_Oracle`
2. Installed oracle instant client from https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html - basic 64 bit version
3. verified python installed is 64 bit too. see below

```
> python
Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 11:52:54) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`
```

4. set my env variables for both my system and user as path=C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6
5. installed VS redistributable 2017 (64 bit again)

still continues to keep throwing the same error.

As a desperate measure i set, PATH=C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6;%PATH% before running the python script; still throws the same error.

Any help how I can steer through this?

There are a couple of answers here, none of them worked through though -
[cx_Oracle error. DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119490/cx-oracle-error-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-client-library)

Comment: What directory does OCI.DLL reside in on your computer?

Comment: It resides in C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6\instantclient_19_6

Comment: I also tried modifying the path variable to C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6\instantclient_19_6 just to see if that's the issue. but same error.

Comment: are you sure that the path is added to **system** path variable ?

Comment: yes. it is added to system path variable. I can see it present there

Comment: You mentioned about the client reside in **C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6\instantclient_19_6** in the comment but **C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6** in the question.

Comment: That is because i followed word to word instructions given in https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html. However, to resolve this issue i changed the path to oci.dll path.. i.e., C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_6\instantclient_19_6