# Python connection to Oracle Database Error DPI-1047

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Hy I try to connect with my oracle database but I have error. I'm a beginner in python i try find answer in documentation but It to hard for me.

```
Python version :
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Oracle version :
11.2.0.1.0
```

My cod is simple :

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import cx_Oracle
    
    
    engine =  create_engine('oracle://user:password@ho.st.name:port/SID')
    result = engine.execute('select * FROM TABLE')
```

In result I get an error :

```
    Exception has occurred: DatabaseError
    (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found".
```

Comment: When in doubt, read the manual: [Installing cx_Oracle on Windows](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows).    The DPI-1047 should have given you a URL with installation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The Python `cx_Oracle` library is dependent of `Oracle Client library`.

Download the Oracle Client library from here : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the library has not been installed properly.
Refer
[cx_Oracle error. DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119490/cx-oracle-error-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-client-library)

To install cx_Oracle

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```