# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Both my python executable and oci.dll(the library causing this error) are 32-bits architecture but I get this error every time.
what should I do?

Comment: See if this discussion helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119490/cx-oracle-error-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-client-library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cx\_Oracle error. DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119490/cx-oracle-error-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-client-library)

Comment: According to the error message your python and/or your oci.dll is the 64-bit version, not 32-bit. Perhaps you mixed up your Oracle installation. If you need to install both, the 32-bit and the 64-bit Oracle client follow this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32/24120100#24120100