# How to install and configure Oracle Instant Client on a Linux Azure Web App

Tags: python, linux, oracle, azure, client

I have been struggling for several days to install the Oracle Instant Client files on a Linux Web App Service. I am running a Python/Flask web app on it and I want to use the cx_Oracle library which requires Oracle Instant Client.
This is something that I have done on another server but I cannot seem to replicate/configure it on Azure Web App service.
At the moment I keep getting the error message:
`"Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".`

What I have done:
Downloaded instantclient_21_1 (64 bits) from [this link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html), then unzipped it

```
cd /home/site/wwwroot/
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
```

I installed libaio1 with `apt-get install libaio1`.

I then need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to home/site/wwwroot/instantclient_21_1.

I tried `echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/site/wwwroot/instantclient_21_1 >> ~/.bashrc` but it doesn't work because bashrc cannot be saved in Azure Web App ("Any data outside '/home' is not persisted").

I created an applicationHost.xdt file as said on [this link](https://azureossd.github.io/2016/02/23/access-oracle-databases-from-azure-web-apps-using-oci8-drivers-with-php/) but it did not work.

I went to the Azure Web App Settings > Configuration > Application Settings, then set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /home/site/wwwroot/instantclient_21_1 but it didn't work.

Finally in my Python script I tried `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir='/home/site/wwwroot/instantclient_21_1')` and I still get the same error message.

Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: xdt is used to windows webapp. Pls check this post. https://askubuntu.com/questions/950313/how-to-set-ld-library-path-permanently

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but if someone's still struggling with this like me for a week

The solution is pretty simple.

Download the Oracle instant client from the link in the question and unzip it anywhere you like (Not in azure).

Move all .dll files from the unzipped folder to the **web app's python folder** through Kudu interface and you are good to go

Follow the link if you have problems.

[cx_Oracle error. DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119490/cx-oracle-error-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-client-library)