# App exe file not connecting to database - DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64 bit Oracle Client library

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I created an app to connect to Oracle and load data to tables. I build exe and it also runs fine on my machine. However when we tried to run on my friend's machine it gives error DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64 bit Oracle Client library.
We explicitly set the PATH variable and pointed to the correct Oracle client
He can connect to database with TOAD with the same path. For some reason the app gives this error.
We made sure that the path used by TOAD is setup as first entry in the PATH variable.
We also tried to setup a new Environmental variable and read from there.
We also tried to explicitly setup the path in the code. But no resolution.

Do I need to install Python on his machine? Or Am I missing something?
I though Oracle client is all needed on machine for the app to work.
Only difference is I am admin of my machine but he is NOT administrator of his machine. But we made sure that oci.dll file has 'Read and Execute' permission for his user.

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119490/cx-oracle-error-dpi-1047-cannot-locate-a-64-bit-oracle-client-library

Comment: Thanks, They all address issues for developer. As a developer everything is fine on my machine. Its the issue on end user machine. End user can have only this app and Oracle client. Also they are not administrators on their machine.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value 64 and run the application on the machine on which the app does not work. Post those results in your question if that doesn't resolve the issue for you!

Answer (score 0):

The user machine needed 64 bit Oracle. We installed 64 bit client on user machine and added the path to PATH variable and moved up ABOVE the path 32 bit client on user machine.
Everything started working.